# How to know who is(are) the currently logged in user(s)

Tags: spring-mvc

How to know who is(are) the currently logged in user(s) in a spring MVC web application so that we can present the jsp views accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to get logged in User details.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
            if (principal instanceof User) {
                return ((User) principal);
            }
        }
```

And in JSP page you can get logged in user details like below.

```
${pageContext['request'].userPrincipal.principal.id}
```

Comment: What about the JSP pages , how do I control their view according to the user. I mean what things I could use in the JSPS @Alien

Comment: Will the server let me know who are the users accessing the application simultaneously through this way. can you provide me some link to tutorial on  authorization part. I am done with authentication and I am stuck with this @ Alien